# Is there a proverb of proverbs?

Tags: popular-refrains, proverbs, proverb-requests

In my language (Vietnamese), there is a proverb (or at least a common saying) that proverbs are the treasure of our ancestors. Do we have such proverbs, [proverbial phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proverbial_phrases) or sayings in English?

There is a book [Proverbs and sayings from ancient times - the imperishable treasure of Bulgaria](https://smile.amazon.com/Proverbs-sayings-ancient-times-imperishable-ebook/dp/B00M4MJYVS). Maybe we can say "proverbs are the imperishable treasure from ancient times"?

Comment: I've often heard [*For every proverb there is an opposite proverb*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22every+proverb+there+is+an+opposite+proverb%22) and variations thereof. In Anglophone cultures, "proverbs, saws, sayings* are likely to be dismissed as "old wives' tales" rather than revered as representing "the wisdom of our ancestors".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfgang Mieder, [*A Dictionary of American Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&pg=PA337&dq=%22Mad+folks+and+proverbs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8zdantI7bAhWJsVQKHb8eBywQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Mad%20folks%20and%20proverbs%22&f=false) (1992) lists three sayings that field researchers collected in various parts of the United States:

> Mad folks and proverbs reveal many truths. [*Recorded in Illinois.*]
>
> Proverbs are the daughters of daily experience. [*Recorded in Alabama and in New York.*]
>
> Proverbs are the wisdom of nations. [*Recorded in Wisconsin; traced to Francis Bacon's* Novum Organum {*published in 1620*}.]

Rosalind Fregusson, *The Facts on File Dictionary of Proverbs* (1983) renders the Bacon proverb as follows:

> The genius, wit, and spirit of a nation are discovered in its proverbs.

Of course, if it first appeared in the *Novum Organum*, Bacon must have written it in Latin.

Fergusson lists a number of other proverbs about proverbs, but without specifying their place of origin. My two favorites from her collection are

> Proverbs are like butterflies, some are caught, others fly away.

and

> Wise men make proverbs and fools repeat them.

This last saying goes back at least as far as James Kelly, [*A Complete Collection of Scottish Proverbs: Explained and Made Intelligible to the English Reader*](https://books.google.com/books?id=n27YAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22wise+men+make+proverbs+and+fools%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7g5rAt47bAhWmv1QKHeMVBrM4ChDoAQgzMAI#v=onepage&q=%22wise%20men%20make%20proverbs%20and%20fools%22&f=false) (1721). Kelly explains its origin as follows:

> *Fools make Feasts and wise Men eat them.*
>
> This was once said to a great Man in *Scotland*, upon his giving an Entertainment. Who readily answer'd,
>
> *Wise Men make Proverbs and Fools repeat them.*

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few [proverbs about proverbs](http://www.bartleby.com/346/3.html), they say, in English.

> *A good maxim is never out of season. (English).*
>
> *Proverbs are the children of experience. (English).*
>
> *Proverbs are the wisdom of the street. (English).*
>
> *Proverbs lie on the lips of fools. (English).*
>
> *There is no proverb which is not true. (English).*

(D.E. Marvin, comp.  Curiosities in Proverbs.  1916.)